# Understanding GC logs - Tenured Generation too large?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm new to GC, so I'd like to have a second opinion on why is my application spending so much time in GC. From my understanding of these logs:

```
[GC[DefNew: 546176K->546176K(614400K), 0.0000340 secs][Tenured: 1317048K->1316223K(1365376K), 4.3852130 secs] 1863224K->1316223K(1979776K), [Perm : 69684K->69684K(69696K)], 4.3853350 secs] [Times: user=4.39 sys=0.00, real=4.39 secs] 
[GC[DefNew: 546176K->546176K(614400K), 0.0000460 secs][Tenured: 1316223K->1317346K(1365376K), 5.2960840 secs] 1862399K->1317346K(1979776K), [Perm : 69684K->69684K(69696K)], 5.2962270 secs] [Times: user=5.29 sys=0.00, real=5.30 secs] 
[GC[DefNew: 546176K->546176K(614400K), 0.0000270 secs][Tenured: 1317346K->1317499K(1365376K), 4.4173580 secs] 1863522K->1317499K(1979776K), [Perm : 69684K->69684K(69696K)], 4.4175090 secs] [Times: user=4.42 sys=0.00, real=4.42 secs] 
[GC[DefNew: 546176K->546176K(614400K), 0.0000490 secs][Tenured: 1317499K->1317540K(1365376K), 4.3927550 secs] 1863675K->1317540K(1979776K), [Perm : 69684K->69684K(69696K)], 4.3929240 secs] [Times: user=4.40 sys=0.00, real=4.39 secs]
```

My bottleneck is the Tenured Generation, which is big (over 1GB) and thus the collection takes over 4s. Am I right? Does the fact that its size is not decreasing affect the collection duration? Is this (relative size of the Tenured Generation) anything I should be concerned about?